# Compiling PHP 5.4, OpenLDAP, OpenSSL and Cyrus SASL on Windows

Tags: php, ssl, dll

I have a question: I am building PHP 5.4 to a dll (php5ts.dll). This PHP should use openldap, openssl and cyrus sasl (static). I do these steps in the given order:

1. Build OpenSSL (1.0.1m)
2. Build DB Berkeley (for Cyrus SASL) (6.1.23)
3. Build Cyrus SASL (2.1.26)
4. Build OpenLDAP (2.4.39)
5. Build PHP (5.4.41)

When building PHP, I set the following flags (with some others): `--with-mcrypt=static`, `--with-openssl=static`, `--with-ldap=static`

I write the log of the compilation to a file and there I can see the:

```
-----------------------
| Extension  | Mode   |
-----------------------
| ...        | ...    |
| ldap       | static |
| mcrypt     | static |
| openssl    | static |
| ...        | ...    |
-----------------------
```

I also set all path to the include files and libraries. No errors occurr during the compilation.

The problem is the following: When I take php5ts.dll, the openssl dlls and the libsasl dll, and trying to connect to a ldap server over ssl, then this does not work. When using another tool like `LDAP Browser` and connecting there to a ldap server over ssl, then this works. 
Connecting to a ldap server without ssl works without any problems.

I assume, that I should change something in the PHP 5.4 build to get this done, but I do not know what. Can someone help me?